# Using requests of python, i can't post data

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to parse cross-section data from x-com. So i used requests module and post. I successfully post datas including energy data. If there is no problem, i can get cross-section data of 2Mev-20Mev energy. But x-com shows me cross-section data of 0.001Mev-10000Mev. What is the problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
energy=2
with requests.Session() as session:



    datas={'ZNum':31,
           'NumAdd':1,
           'OutOpt':'PIC',
           'Graph6':'on',
           'Output':'on',
           'Resol':'-r72.73x72.73',
           'WindowXmin':energy,
           'WindowXmax':energy*10,}
    res=session.post('https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom3_1',data=datas)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

'https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom3_1' put origin 'https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Xcom/html/xcom1.html'>'https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom2'

Comment: Where on the website are these data? When I hit your url in a browser I get an error...

Comment: Oh, i am sorry for my unkindness. The path of 'https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom3_1' is 'https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Xcom/html/xcom1.html'>'https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom2'>'https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom3_1'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Set the energy - multiply by 10 in the payload. Query the endpoint, extract relevant pieces and store in file.

Pretty basic. Hope this solves your problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set the energy - you proposed a value of 2
energy = 2

# set the right payload - multiply the energymax by 10 - you wanted this
payload = {
    "ZNum": 31,
    "OutOpt": "PIC",
    "Graph6": "on",
    "NumAdd": 1,
    "Output": "on",
    "WindowXmin": energy,
    "WindowXmax": energy*10,
    "ResizeFlag": "on"
}

# define path to store data
path_to_output_file = "C:/myfile.txt"

# define the correct endpoint
url = "https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Xcom/xcom3_1"

# make the request to the endpoint
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

# load the response into BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

# identify the rows that hold your data (they share same bgcolor)
trs = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'bgcolor': '#FFFFCC'})

# open a file to store the data
with open(path_to_output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    # loop through the rows and extract the values
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        # list comprehension that finds and then joins the values of all columns by a semicolon
        # the first td is blank and therefor omitted
        data_line = ";".join([td.get_text() for td in tds[1:]])
        # write the data to the file
        f.write("{}\n".format(data_line))
```

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to accept the answer to close to question.